# Clear interval if any and then set new one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to clear an interval if it is already set and after this I need to set a new one. Here is my code:

```
if (errorchannels.length != 0) {
  clearInterval(errorInterval1);
  var errorInterval1 = setInterval(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < errorchannels.length; i++) {
      $('[errorid=' + errorchannels[i] + ']').closest('.channels').toggleClass('errorClass1');;
    }
  }, 500);
}
```

Interval gets set few times, this means, old interval with the same name does not get cleared. How do I fix this?

**NOTE:** The interval might not be set when I'm trying to clear it.

Comment: You've to collect the interval ids for example into an array.

Comment: Why would you clear the interval if you're gonna set another one?

Comment: `errorInterval1` is scoped as a var.  I would assume you are having an issue with the variable being scoped too low.

Comment: @Teemu I'm doing this, errorchannels is an array of ids

Comment: But you're not using that array to clear the intervals ... You've to iterate through the array, and clear the interval in every member of the array. Also, the provided code doesn't tell, that `errorInterval1` would be pushed to that array. Maybe you should add more context to the code ..?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you're defining `errorInterval1` at the wrong spot.  If your code was all that existed... Here's how it would work:

- **Step 1**: set `errorInterval1` to `undefined`
- **Step 2**: Start executing... get to `clearInterval`, and it's still `undefined`
- **Step 3**: Start the timer and save it to `errorInterval1`
- **Step 4**: Forget about everything next time, and go back to **Step 1**

Instead, declare `errorInterval1` somewhere else, in a persistent scope (make it a global variable).